# How to use sorted function discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I use the following code to make a points table:

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How many total teams are there?")
    t = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**__Today's Result:__**", color=0x03f8fc)
    
    lst = []
    
    for i in range(t):
        await ctx.send(f"Enter team {i+1} name :")
        teamname = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How many kills did they get?")
        firstnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How much Position points did they score?")
        secondnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        lst.append((teamname, firstnum, secondnum))  # append to results
        
    lstSorted = sorted(lst, key = lambda x: int(x[1]) + int(x[2]))  # sort results by kills + points
    
    for teamname, firstnum, secondnum in lstSorted:  # process embed
        embed.add_field(name=teamname, value=f'Kills: {firstnum}\nPosition Pt: {secondnum}\nTotal Pt: {firstnum+secondnum}',inline=False)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The thing is that code works well but I want it to sort the result on the basis of total points into descending order and that doesn't work, I don't know what I am doing wrong in here.

Also if you can suggest me something for better visualization of the result , you are most welcome.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to choose which value you would like to sort by, either kills or points. You can't have both

Comment: @Abdulaziz ofc you can, don't spread wrong info. Also I don't see what's wrong with the code, it will correctly sort by `kills + points`? I'm pretty sure you want to add `reversed=True` keyword to your sorted function since that will make it go from highest to lowest.

Comment: @BrainDead let's assume `A kills=10 and score=5` and `B kills=2 and score=9` Which one should be first? either you make the priority of sorting to kills or score. if they have the same kills (assuming primary parameter) then you check for score. maybe i did not make it clear at first.